# How do I implement OpenSSL's EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp in Bouncy Castle?

Tags: c#, java, encryption, openssl, bouncycastle

I need a little assistance porting the OpenSSL function  [EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EC_POINT_new.html) in C# or Java
.

Though I can use Bouncy Castle (preferred), I am open to building it from scratch.

The C++ method signature looks like this:

```
int EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp(const EC_GROUP *group, EC_POINT *p,
   const BIGNUM *x, int y_bit, BN_CTX *ctx);
```

From OpenSSL:

> Points can also be described in terms of their compressed co-ordinates. For a point (x, y), for any given value for x such that the point is on the curve there will only ever be two possible values for y. Therefore a point can be set using the EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp and EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GF2m functions where x is the x co-ordinate and y_bit is a value 0 or 1 to identify which of the two possible values for y should be used.

Can anyone assist in the math needed?  I'm having trouble understanding the source and want to make sure I port it over correctly

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this function is to setup a point `P` using the provided `x` coordinate and `y_bit`.  You can look on [x-coordinate,y_bit] as a compressed form of (x-coordinate,y-coordinate); both of them represent point P.

In Weierstrass equation (GFp)

```
y^2 = x^3 + a*x + b,
```

suppose y is in its modulo form (0 <= y < p), then `y_bit` is the LSB of y. As you can see, y is one of the square roots of  x^3 + a*x + b. And it can be proven that each root has different y_bit. This is why you can use y_bit to determine which y (root) should be used.

Take `ec_GFp_simple_set_compressed_coordinates` in `ecp_oct.c`(OpenSSL-1.0.1e) for example, here's what it does:

- Calculate x^3 + a*x + b
- Calculate y, the square root of x^3 + a*x + b
- Compare y_bit with LSB of y. If different, y = -y (mod p)
- Set affine coordinate (x,y) to point P

Comment: Thank you!  I'm leaving this open for a bit longer hoping someone (or I will) post the Bouncy Castle source in C# or Java

Comment: Could you elaborate, or perhaps provide some code / pseudo code for steps 2 and 3. In these steps, is y supposed to be in it's raw or modulo form?